# How is the smallest positive representable floating-point value determined?

Tags: c#, floating-point

Just curious how the things work. 
The float max and epsilon values are

```
Single MaxValue = 3.40282347E+38F; // derived from 1.000.. * 2^128
Single Epsilon = 1.401298E-45F; // probably from substracting (1.00..01 - 1.00..0) * 2^-128 ?
```

But the smallest positive value should be around 1/MaxValue or 1*2^-127 which makes ^-39 or ^-38 power of decimal digit. So how is possible for float to store something below power -38 (to -45)?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,43

Comment: “Epsilon” is usually used to refer to the step between representable numbers, most often the step from 1 to the next representable value. The value you are asking about is the minimum positive representable value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Microsoft does define [`Single.Epsilon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.epsilon) to be the smallest positive IEEE 754 binary32 subnormal, though. I have no idea why they chose such a confusing name. This confusion led to IronPython incorrectly reporting the corresponding `Double.Epsilon` value for `sys.float_info.epsilon`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very small numbers, IEEE 754 floating point uses normalized values that allow for smaller intervals.

> In computer science, denormal numbers or denormalized numbers (now often called subnormal numbers) fill the underflow gap around zero in floating-point arithmetic. Any non-zero number with magnitude smaller than the smallest normal number is 'subnormal'.
>
> In a normal floating-point value, there are no leading zeros in the significand; instead leading zeros are moved to the exponent. So 0.0123 would be written as 1.23 × 10−2. Denormal numbers are numbers where this representation would result in an exponent that is below the minimum exponent (the exponent usually having a limited range). Such numbers are represented using leading zeros in the significand.

For more information, see the [Wikipedia page on denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) or [the page on IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Single_precision) that also lists the numbers you stumpled upon (10^-45).

> The positive and negative numbers closest to zero (represented by the denormalized value with all 0s in the exponent field and the binary value 1 in the fraction field) are
> ±2 ^ −149 ≈ ± 1.40130×10 ^ −45

Comment: Thanks, I missed the moment when exponent part is all 0s.